# How to solve recurrence when particular solution is undefined?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations

$u(n)−7 u(n−1)−18 u(n−2) = 9^n$

I have found the complement solution to be $A(−2)^n+B(9)^n$. And have done these steps to find particular solution:

$U_n^{(p)} = C.9^n$

$U_{n-1}^{(p)} = C*9^{n-1}$

$U_{n-2}^{(p)} = C*9^{n-2}$

Sub into original:

$C.9^n−7.C*9^{n-1}−18.C*9^{n-2} = 9^n$

Factorise and Divide by $9^{n-2}$

$C(9^2-7*9-18)=9^2$

Solving for $C$ I get $9^2/0$ which is undefined.

What am I supposed to do? Thanks

Comment: The trouble is that $9^n$ is a solution of the homogeneous recurrence $u_n-7u_{n-1}-9u_{n-2}=0$. Try $n9^n$ instead.

Answer (score 1):

For any term $P(n)\lambda^n$ appear on RHS where $P(n)$ is a polynomial in $n$ with degree $p$.  If $\lambda$ is a root of multiplicity $m$ for the characteristic polynomial associated with LHS, the particular solution will contain a term of the form $Q(n)\lambda^n$ where $Q(n)$ is a polynomial of degree $q = p + m$.

For your case, the characteristic polynomial for LHS is

$$\lambda^2 - 7\lambda - 18 = (\lambda + 2)(\lambda - 9)$$

Since $9$ is a simple root for this, a term $9^n$ on RHS leads to a term of
the form $(a + bn) 9^n$ in the particular solution.